# nvc++ yields "error: expression must have a constant value" while g++ and clang++ do not

Tags: c++, c++20, nvcc, stdarray

I am writing some software (C++20) in which many things are evaluated during compile time. Using g++ (version > 9) or clang++ (version > 10) the software compiles just fine on Ubuntu 22.04. However, when trying to compile it using nvc++ (version 22.5-0) I receive several identical errors.

A minimal code example is a file `test.cxx` containing

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

static constexpr std::array<std::array<double, 7>, 5> make_array()
{
  std::array<std::array<double, 7>, 5> result;

  for (unsigned int fct = 0; fct < 5; ++fct)
    for (unsigned int pt = 0; pt < 7; ++pt)
      result[fct][pt] = 2.;

  return result;
}

static constexpr std::array<std::array<double, 7>, 5> const_array = make_array();

int main()
{
  std::cout << const_array[3][4] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Running `g++-10 -std=gnu++20 test.cxx -o test; ./test` gives an output `2`, and `clang++-11 -std=gnu++20 test.cxx -o test; ./test` also yields `2`. However, using `nvc++ -std=gnu++20 test.cxx -o test; ./test` with `nvc++` version 22.5-0 yields

```
"test.cxx", line 15: error: expression must have a constant value
  static constexpr std::array<std::array<double, 7>, 5> const_array = make_array();
                                                                      ^
"test.cxx", line 12: note: access to uninitialized object
    return result;
           ^
```

Why does it not compile using `nvc++` and can one fix this somehow?

**UPDATES:**

- I have tested the very same setup on Ubuntu 20.04, and observed the same errors.
- I have tried the compile flags `-std=c++2a` and `-std=c++20`, and observed the same errors.

Comment: Have you tried with the `-std=c++2a` or `-std=c++20` flags, instead of `-std=gnu++20`? Alternatively, assuming it's an issue with incomplete or incorrect C++20 support in nvc, I can provide an equivalent that works under C++17 standards.

Comment: @AdrianMole No, the most likely cause is that Ubuntu 22.04 is not supported. In the past i had a very similar issue where the ubuntu version that i was using was not supported. Additionally, in the list linked in my answer it is mentioned that C++20 is supported but Ubuntu 22.04 is not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately, the alternative compilation flags did not help. I guess that C++20 is not fully supported by nvc at the moment---at least that is the only thing I can imagine right now.

It will be great if the same result can be achieved using C++17 only!

Comment: You are right, the [NVC documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk/compilers/hpc-compilers-user-guide/index.html) also says it only supports C++17. You can @ people like @AdrianMole to notify them of a response, by default only the author of the question or answer is notified.

Comment: Thank you, sigma for your remark. Also, thank you @AdrianMole for the comment. It appears to underline the reason.

Comment: Like I said, I *can* provide code that works with the C++17 Standard. However, it would only address the issue(s) posted in your given example, and *may* not be applicable more widely. If you edit your Q to be more specific, I can (maybe) post a helpful(?) answer. (Also, I'm not entirely sure that I can properly explain *why* it would work in C++17, but that your code requires C++20.)

Comment: I have the same issue where I tried compiling code using on `boost::hana::filter`. Their code should be C++14, but it yields the exact same error. I highly recommend posting the issue in [their forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/accelerated-computing/hpc-compilers/299) which I haven't done as I missed a MRE.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thank you very much! Unfortunately, the program throws many similar errors (in different locations). This is just a significantly simplified example. Thus, I fear that it will be most economic to wait for nvc++ to support C++20.